# Geting started: Android development online database

Tags: android

Im developing an android app, and would like to have a database stored somewhere online. My app is a native app.  I checked the android development page and it just shows how to store to the SQLite database.

Are there any resources out there that would help with this? Are there any framework such as the ADO.net entity framework that can with with doing databasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest and easiest way I know of, is using a webservice which would interact with the online DB (PHP and MySQL works great together, and also many free web host provides them.

Then you can perform `POST` or `GET` requests from your app to the webservice, which will query the DB (update it, read from it, etc)

https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysql+webservice

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Links to get  you started...